# KnockoutJS - How do i use filter out the markers on the maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

i have a list view of all the items each has a marker object. so far, the filter function works on the list view, where it removes items that don't match what the user is typing in the search field. I want the filter function to start removing markers on the map that don't match the search.

```
var ViewModel = function(list) {
    var self = this;
    self.allPlaces = ko.observableArray(list.map(function(place) {
        return new Point(place);
    }));
    self.visiblePlaces = ko.observableArray(self.allPlaces().map(function(place) {
        var markerOptions = {
            map: map,
            position: place.pos,
            title: place.name,
            icon: image,
            optimized: false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        }
        place.marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        return place;
    }));
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.search = ko.observable("");
    self.searchResult = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        var q = self.search();
        return self.allPlaces().filter(function(place) {
            return ((place.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0) || (place.type.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `visiblePlaces` is just a copy of `allPlaces`, that adds a `marker` member as it is created. That seems a misguided approach.